# A simple relation on constants

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lambda > 0 $ and $\epsilon >0$ are two constant such that $ \lambda + \epsilon <1$, I want to show that $\lambda^{-1} - \epsilon >1$.

Could anyone help?

Comment: $\lambda (1+\epsilon) =\lambda +\lambda \epsilon <\lambda +\epsilon <1$.

Comment: I got $1+\dfrac{\epsilon}{\lambda}< \lambda^{-1}$ what to do next ?

Comment: See my solution below @Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lambda + \epsilon <1$ and $\lambda>0,\epsilon>0$, we have $0<\lambda<1$, which indicates $\epsilon/\lambda>\epsilon$. Divide both sides by $\lambda$ we get $1+\epsilon/\lambda<\lambda^{-1}$ i.e. $\lambda^{-1}-\epsilon/\lambda>1$. And hence $\lambda^{-1}-\epsilon>\lambda^{-1}-\epsilon/\lambda>1$.

Answer (score 2):

$0<\lambda + \epsilon <1$ so $0<\lambda<1$. Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda + \lambda\epsilon&<&\lambda+\epsilon<1\\
1+\epsilon&<&\frac{1}{\lambda}\\
1&<&\frac{1}{\lambda}-\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda+\epsilon <1 \implies {\lambda}^{-1}(\lambda+\epsilon)<{\lambda}^{-1} \implies 1+{\lambda}^{-1} \epsilon < {\lambda}^{-1} \implies {\lambda}^{-1}-{\lambda}^{-1}\epsilon>1$

Now as $0<\lambda <1$, we have $\lambda^{-1}>1$ and thus

$\lambda^{-1} \epsilon > \epsilon \implies -\epsilon > -\lambda^{-1} \epsilon \implies \lambda^{-1} -\epsilon > \lambda^{-1} -\lambda^{-1} \epsilon  >1$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to show it using the geometric series for $0<\epsilon <1$:
$$\frac 1{1-\epsilon} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^n>1+\epsilon$$

$$\lambda+\epsilon<1 \Rightarrow \frac 1{\lambda} >\frac 1{1-\epsilon}>1+\epsilon$$